# Creating entity with external dependency inside the aggregateroot?

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design, microservices, hexagonal-architecture

Okay, so, I'm working on an AuthService for my microservices system.

I'm putting plenty of logic around single instance of User inside of it itself, just so I can avoid repeating code, breaking SRP or anemic domain models.

.. but now I've stumbled upon a certain problem, to be precise:

I have this method inside `User` entity:

```
    public Token SignIn(string username, string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Username cannot be null or empty");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Password cannot be null or empty");

        if (Password != password)
            throw new Exception("Password mismatch");

        return Token.Create(this, TokenType.Session, "???");
    }
```

The problem with this is, **token value is supposed to be generated via ITokenValueProvider**.

I only see 4 solutions to this problem - all but one of them would break SRP, create a leaky abstraction or break DDD.

a) Add `string tokenValue` to `SignIn` and then generate value on the service and push it deeper.

e.g.: `public Token SignIn(string username, string password, string tokenValue)`

b) Add `ITokenValueProvider tokenizer` to `SignIn` and then generate it inside `User.SignIn`

c) Add `ITokenValueProvider tokenizer` to `public static Token.Create()` and then generate it there.

d) Replace SignIn with `CanSignIn` and then generate token on the service - this solution is the one that would cause no antipatterns, other than being generally ugly and disallows me to store logic around signing-in inside the entity.

Any ideas :) ?

Comment: There might be a clean solution that uses events. In this method a UserLoggedIn event could be emitted and the token service in the application layer responds to that. But getting that token to the user would be the next challenge.

Comment: @RikD That sounds like solution a), but instead of passing tokenValue, I pass the Token instance

Comment: I doubt `Token` is part of your domain, rather, an _implementation detail_ within your application/infrastructure layer. Keep it there. We could imagine all sorts of different ways of managing auth from an application-level PoV right? **d** is the best solution listed above, but keep the name `SignIn` and don't return a `bool` (just throw). To be completely honest though, I don't think _any_ of the above should be in your domain. `User` doesn't sound like a DDD entity to me. What do `Users` _do_?

Comment: @king-side-slide I've decided that the service isn't complex enough for full DDD.
I've used Hexagonal Arch with good practices from DDD (like bounding contexts, non-anemic entities etc.).

The issue is solved.